# How to Connect DB using WebDriverIO Automation

Tags: javascript, automation, devops, ui-automation, webdriver-io

I m trying to fetch value from DB ,from One module using sql queries and same value need to match with other Module on UI Page,

Let's Say we run SQL in module A -->select SUM(BILLING_AMOUNT) from customer where country='Germany'
(Consider output as 10256 EUR)

We need to check above 10256 EUR should display on Page in Module B

I m working in WebDriverIO Automation ,can some one guide me how I can connect DB and run query in WebDriverIO(java script) and check exact value in Module B

Comment: try using api , and fetch data using mock , axio , node fetch then do assertion using expect().toHaveText()